# Predefined function in c++

Tags: c++

This is my first time on this web site. I have been having a problem but I haven`t been able to figure it out. I have been trying to implement a predefined function into my code but I am not sure how to do so. In my Task I was given an open brief asking me simply to design a password protected calculator. I designed the calculator and handed it in to my teacher. He then asked me to add a predefined function. Now I am not sure how to do this or even how I would start. Could any one give me some example of a predefined function similar to my code.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char op;
 float num1, num2;
 int correct_password = 1998;
 int password = 0;
 int counter = 0;
 int attempt = 0;

 while (attempt <= 3) {
  cout << "Enter your password: ";
  cin >> password;
  attempt = attempt + 1;

  if (password != correct_password) {
   cout << "Incorrect password combination. Please try again." << "\n" << endl;
  } else {
   break;
  }
 }
 if (attempt >= 3) {
  return 0;
 }

 cout << "Access granted." << endl;

 //Asks you to enter an operator to use in your calculation
 cout << "Enter operator either + or - or * or /: ";
 cin >> op;

 //Asks you to enter 2 numbers
 cout << "Enter two operands: ";
 cin >> num1 >> num2;

 //Searches for which operator you have selected and Either *-+/ the number depending on choice
 switch (op) {
 case '+':
  cout << num1 + num2;
  break;

 case '-':
  cout << num1 - num2;
  break;

 case '*':
  cout << num1 * num2;
  break;

 case '/':
  cout << num1 / num2;
  break;

  //If entered operator is incorrect closes down the program
 default:
  cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
  break;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the trouble. I am not quite sure if I am going about asking this the right way. so I will apologies before hand if I am not specific enough or if I am doing ti wrong :).

Comment: What's a predefined function?

Comment: Here is an example of a predefined function int function_name(int parameters)
{
    int something = 1;
    return parameters + something;
}

Comment: Though not sure how this can be used sadly :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edit:: added some explanation)

I can't know what exactly your teacher wanted, but it might be something like this:

```
void foo(float a, float b){
    return a+4*b;
}
```

Allowing your calculator to use a function like that would work in the following way:

```
... //Your previous code here

switch(op){

    ... // Your other switches here

    case 'f':
        cout<<foo(num1,num2)<<endl;
    break;
}

... //Your following code here
```

The 'f' here stands for the command "EXECUTE PREDEFINED FUNCTION" instead of '+' for "ADD" or '-' for "SUBTRACT".
That way you could have a predefined function and execute that on your numbers.

In this case we would see the entred number num1 be added to four times the entered number num2

I hope it helped :)

Comment: Yes this is great. Thank you very much. you were very helpful :)

Comment: Before I forget. What do you mean by your other switches here? do you mean the case statement?

Comment: @AlexanderMolyneux-child , sorry for being gone for the last few days.

By other switches I mean those cases you already had, like '+','-','/' or '*'.  Great work, by the way. Hope everything went well :)

Answer (score 0):

these function are in library `#include<math.h>` You need to use this header file in order to use those function in your code . 
It includes predefined functions such as

```
sqrt(number);
```

This function is used to find square root of the argument passed to this function.

```
pow(number);
```

This is used to find the power of the given number.

```
trunc(number);
```

This function truncates the decimal value from floating point value and returns integer value

Comment: Oh I see. So predefined code is something that the program has defined for you with a specific task in mind. I am having a little difficulty understanding your indented code. Not entirely understanding where these segments of code would go in the program. I have only just started so I am sorry if I sound a little stupid :(

Comment: first you need to include #include<math.h> header file. then in your body of program use cout <<sqrt(2); this will calculate the square root of 2 automatically.